# Interactive UI with dynamic areas

Tags: java, android, user-interface

Going to make a pretty statistic part for my app and saw a pretty good looking UI (see below). What I'm asking is what's the approach? I have a few ideas, for example drawing multiple ImageButtons (one for every text field) and paint the background the same color as the ImageButtons. 
This if i want each of the texts to be clickable, in the example picture for example pressing 18c fires one action and pressing Cambridge another action.

How would you approach this? 
What components to use? 
Want to do as much as possible in xml, but I'll take suggestions in code too. Whatever is better for you.

EDIT:
Found a good example about how to solve the listView part:
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

[image]

Comment: You want an idea how to make that xml above?

Comment: I don't expect a full xml,  but an approach, something to get me on the right track :)

Comment: maybe you should use a customized list view. that will help for the above layout.

Comment: Well the big top red rectangle is a good candidate for a `RelativeLayout`, then below that (or included) should be a `ListView`.